# I'm working on JavaFX application, got stuck with an error. Can anyone explain this behavior?

Tags: java, javafx

I have an XML configurations file, upon extending some options to the file, I stumbled across this error. can anyone explain the error?

```
 Exception in thread "OSCReceiver" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at osc.netutil.OSCException.<init>(OSCException.java:92)
    at osc.netutil.OSCTransmitter$UDPOSCTransmitter.send(OSCTransmitter.java:738)
    at osc.netutil.OSCTransmitter.send(OSCTransmitter.java:503)
    at osc.netutil.OSCTransmitter.send(OSCTransmitter.java:539)
    at osc.netutil.OSCClient.send(OSCClient.java:476)
    at motioncomposer.library.Receiver.sendMotionComposerStateToAllGUIs(Receiver.java:177)
    at controlmodule.motioncomposer.ReceiverGUI.msgHandler(ReceiverGUI.java:48)
    at motioncomposer.library.Receiver$1.messageReceived(Receiver.java:60)
    at osc.netutil.OSCReceiver.dispatchMessage(OSCReceiver.java:883)
    at osc.netutil.OSCReceiver.dispatchPacket(OSCReceiver.java:863)
    at osc.netutil.OSCReceiver.flipDecodeDispatch(OSCReceiver.java:851)
    at osc.netutil.OSCReceiver$UDPOSCReceiver.run(OSCReceiver.java:1067)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name NetUtilStrings, locale en_GB
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(Unknown Source)
    at osc.netutil.NetUtil.<clinit>(NetUtil.java:47)
    ... 13 more
```

Comment: Did you include a ResourceBundle named NetUtilStrings in your program, or not?

Comment: @VGR I don't find such bundle in the osc library for my udp communication http://opensoundcontrol.org/implementation/netutil-osc-library-java . How to resolve the error?

Comment: Finally, I resolved it by linking with the latest version of the libraries it has NetUtilStrings.properties. The root cause was to do with the buffer size.

Comment: you might consider to answer your own question: being a versioning issue others might experience something similar :)